# Почему неправильно рассчитывается высота через Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

На словах не очень просто объяснить, поэтому я прикладываю скриншоты с пояснениями.

Вот ссылка на песочницу:
https://codepen.io/codepen_user_2020/pen/eYpPYKK

В коде я приложил Javascript для расчета высоты.

```
$(function () {
    // ----------------------------------------
    // Необходимые функции для работы
    // ----------------------------------------
    function getRowsWithItems() {
        let $prod = $('.active .product');
        let rowsWithItems = [];

        // --------------------------
        // 3 карточки в строке
        // --------------------------
        if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
            $prod.each(function () {
                let $p = $(this);
                // Берем первую карточку в каждой строке. И с помощью нее получаем все карточки в одной строке.
                if ($p.is(':nth-of-type(3n+1)')) {
                    // Все карточки в одной строке
                    let itemsInRow = [];

                    itemsInRow.push($p);
                    let $next = $p.next();
                    if ($next.length) {
                        itemsInRow.push($next);

                        let $nextNext = $next.next();
                        if ($nextNext.length) {
                            itemsInRow.push($nextNext);
                        }
                    }

                    rowsWithItems.push(itemsInRow);
                }
            });
        }

        return rowsWithItems;
    }


    function setValuesToItemsInRow(itemsInRow) {
        let maxHeight = 0;
        let maxMinHeight = 0;

        $.each(itemsInRow, function () {
            let $e = $(this);
            let $eProductContent = $e.find('.product__content');

            let curMinHeight = $eProductContent.height();

            let currHeight = parseFloat($e.css('height'));
            console.log('currHeight = ' + currHeight);

            if (curMinHeight > maxMinHeight) {
                maxMinHeight = curMinHeight;
            }
            if (currHeight > maxHeight) {
                maxHeight = currHeight;
            }
        });

        $.each(itemsInRow, function () {
            let $e = $(this);
            let $eProductContent = $e.find('.product__content');

            $eProductContent.css('min-height', maxMinHeight);
            $e.css('height', maxHeight);
        });
    }


    function classMarginToItemsInRow(itemsInRow) {
        let needAddClass = false;

        // Определяем, надо ли добавлять класс
        $.each(itemsInRow, function () {
            let $e = $(this);

            let $showBtn = $e.find('.product__show-btn');
            let $hideBtn = $e.find('.product__hide-btn');
            if ($showBtn.css('display') != 'none' || $hideBtn.css('display') != 'none') {
                needAddClass = true;
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Добавляем или удаляем класс
        $.each(itemsInRow, function () {
            let $e = $(this);
            if (needAddClass) {
                $e.addClass('product_with-margin');
            } else {
                $e.removeClass('product_with-margin');
            }
        });
    }


    function calculateItemsHeight($prod, rowsWithItems) {
        $prod.removeAttr('style');
        $prod.find('.product__content').removeAttr('style');

        for (let i = 0; i < rowsWithItems.length; i++) {
            setValuesToItemsInRow(rowsWithItems[i]);
        }
    }

    // ----------------------------------------
    // Работа скрипта
    // ----------------------------------------
    $(window).on('resize', function () {
        // Если не делать setTimeout, то карточки иногда отображаются некорректно. Например, при переходах между шириной 961, 960, 959.
        // setTimeout(function () {

            let $prod = $('.active .product');
            let rowsWithItems = getRowsWithItems();

            // ------------------------------------
            // Рассчитываем и устанавливаем высоту карточек
            // ------------------------------------
            calculateItemsHeight($prod, rowsWithItems);

        // }, 100);
    }).resize();
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Первое, что бросается в глаза: события вроде `resize` и `scroll`, связанные со сложными калькуляциями и обновлениями DOM, необходимо фильтровать по времени (ищите `debounce/throttle` хелперы).

Второе, это `css media query` и `js` вычисления, которые пересекаются как раз на прохождении через брейкпоинты. Если вы представляете, как работает браузерный ивент луп, то у вас сначала отработает скрипт (вычислится значение в `181px`, после окончания скрипта браузер перекалькулирует значения по css media и применит их. Поэтому контент у вас станет реально меньше, но проставленные через js значения `height` увеличат размер карточки. Именно поэтому setTimeout - абсолютно нормальное решение. Это переносит вычисления на следующий `event loop tick`. В любом случае, используя `debounce` вы сократите количество промежуточных вычислений, пока не закончится `resize` и одновременно это отложит вычисление на следующий тик, что даст правильный вычисленный размер карточки.

Третье, вы используете `float` свойство из лихих нулевых. Пора переходить на [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox), чтобы избежать необходимости вычислять высоты через `js`

```
.section_products.type_1 .tabs .tab {
    margin: 10px -15px 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.section_products.type_1 .product {
    width: calc(33.333% - 30px);
    margin: 15px;
}
```

И можете всю `js` логику в утиль отправить.

Можно попрофайлить происходящее на странице и посмотреть порядок выполнения операций браузером.
Без `setTimeout`:

```
Event: resize -> calculateHeight - высота 181 ставится по предыдущему лейауту
Recalculate Style -> считается css media query styles
Layout
Update Layer Tree   
Paint
Paint
Composite Layers
```

С `setTimeout 0`:

```
Event: resize -> setTimout 0
Update Layer Tree
Composite Layers
Timer Fired -> calculateHeight, высота 181px ставится по предыдущему лейауту 
Recalculate Style -> считается css media query styles
Layout
Update Layer Tree
Paint
Composite Layers
```

C `setTimeout 100`:

```
Event: resize -> setTimout 100
Update Layer Tree   
Composite Layers
Schedule Style Recalculation
Recalculate Style -> считается css media query styles
Layout
Update Layer Tree
Paint -> отрисовывается новый лейаут
... -> еще куча браузерной работы
Timer Fired -> calculateHeight, высота ставится по новому лейауту
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! А можно еще вопрос? Может ли случиться так, что в некоторых браузерах (или на некоторых компах, например, на слабеньких) значения 100 для setTimeout может не хватить? Если да, то setTimeout - все-таки костыль. И очень ненадежный :-( . Если так, то можете, пожалуйста, привести код, который будет работать на всех компах и браузерах? Я то свой код проверить не смогу - правильно я написал или нет. У меня и setTimeout хорошо справляется.

Comment: Хватит значения `0`. Ведь наша задача - это просто перенести вычисление высота на следующий тик, после того, как css по медиа запросу уже вычислится и применится после прохождения брейкпоинта.
Обновил ответ

Comment: А скоро `setTimeout(, 0)` заменим на `requestIdleCallback`, вот заживем.

Comment: @Yugofx , значения 0 не хватает. Можете проверить. Не хватает и значения 50. Надо 100. Но на всех ли компах? Во всех ли браузерах?

Можете все-таки привести рабочий код на JS? Хочется увидеть решение и использовать его в своих проектах дальше.

Comment: @Yugofx, всю js логику в утиль отправить я не могу, т.к. это упрощенный  пример. В реальной задачи без js не обойтись.

Comment: просто именно та задача, которую вы поставили, решается именно так

Comment: @Yugofx , вы можете ответить на вопросы, которые я задал?
1. Хватит ли setTimeout 100 для других браузеров и экранов?
2. Можно ли обойтись без setTimeout 100?

Comment: 1. Природу неправильной калькуляции высоты я вам объяснил, и также подсказал ответ в виде `debounce` или `throttle`. Воспользуетесь вы ей или нет - ваше дело. Под капотом обе функции используют таймауты. Попробуйте проставьте значение 150, это закроет любой вопрос. Костыль это или нет - вопрос странный, ведь весь этот код при наличии `flexbox` - костыль
2. Да, можно, и я оставил для вас рабочий код выше. Воспользуетесь вы им или нет - ваше дело

Comment: @Yugofx , я нашел примеры использования debounce и throttle. Я менял свой код в песочнице, используя код из примеров. Мне это не помогло. 

Вы можете изменить мой код и скинуть мне ссылку? Я не думаю, что это займет больше времени, чем написать комментарий.

Мне кажется, что debounce и throttle здесь не подходят. Но я в этом не уверен, т.к. никогда не использовал их. Я узнал о них только из вашего ответа.

Тот код, который вы привели, мне не подходит. Я хочу не решить задачу другим способом, а получше узнать, как работает JS и JQuery.

Comment: Перечитайте комментарий выше. Если не считаете, что я ответил на ваш вопрос, просто подождите другой ответ.

Comment: @Yugofx, я вижу, что вы дополнили ответ. Спасибо, теперь я знаю про такой полезный инструмент, как профайлер. 
На другом ресурсе мне подсказали, что время, указанное в setTimeout, зависит от окружения, где выполняется код. То есть, для некоторых пользователей 100 может и не хватить. Отсюда вопрос. Можно ли как-нибудь в JS выполнить код ТОЛЬКО ПОСЛЕ ТОГО, как отрисовка произошла? Ранее вы писали про debounce и throttle. Но ведь под капотом у них, как вы сказали, тот же таймаут. То есть, в данном случае эти функции не помогут.

Comment: Если есть способы определения окончания цикла отрисовки, то я такие не знаю. Возможно, у кого-то под рукой есть, самому будет интересно узнать